# Backbone.js with servlet as backend

Tags: servlets, backbone.js

I'm very new to backbone Js. I have gone through the documentation. I'm trying to create a sample aplication with servlet as the backend for saving models. I could not find any help for that. What i need is:

1. is it possible to communicate with servlet? And if so, how to communicate with servlet?  (some sample code)
2. is router required to communicate with  server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone is a client side framework. Its build to work with a RESTful backend. So all you need is a backend that can compute GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE etc. Maybe [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) is a solution for your backend.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.... But Restlet is a framework like Jersey right?can it support servlet? or it can support only POJO class with annotations added using JAX-RS??