# RESTFul WebService in JAVA along servlets

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, rest, servlets

I need to develop a RESTFul web service using pre-existing java servlets. This would mostly involve calling functions that pre-exist  in the servlets package. How can this be done ?

Comment: I am planning to do it using Restlet framework and then importing the other project onto it

Comment: so try it, and if you will not succeed - post the concrete question here.

Answer (score 0):

servlet cant be used as Backend to Restful service..  u may need restful Backend,which can be achieved using Jersey or restlet.
Refer this question 
[Backbone.js with servlet as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830681/backbone-js-with-servlet-as-backend)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this would be to simply add a web service layer that acts as a facade to your servlet layer. To do this, you can build a set of RESTful web services in Java by using a third-party JSR311 framework such as the Jersey framework (http://jersey.java.net), then simply make your web service methods call underlying servlet methods.

If you have more time, the best way to do this would be to abstract the business logic out of your servlets into a separate business logic layer, and possibly even a separate library, and then use that library to provide the business logic for a new set of Web services that you create using a JSR311 implementation like Restlet or Jersey.